# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Encodable

Tags: java, pdf, timestamp, itext, bouncycastle

I am using IText 4.2.0 and bcprov-jdk15-1.43.jar and bctsp-jdk15-1.43.jar for signing pdf. I added these jars by add external jars button in Eclipse. When I execute it gives me following error.

```
ExceptionConverter: java.lang.Exception: Failed to get TSA response from tsaURL
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TSAClientBouncyCastle.getTimeStampToken(TSAClientBouncyCastle.java:185)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TSAClientBouncyCastle.getTimeStampToken(TSAClientBouncyCastle.java:136)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPKCS7.getEncodedPKCS7(PdfPKCS7.java:1236)
at pack1.PDFSigningWithHSM.PDFSigningWithHSM.main(PDFSigningWithHSM.java:489)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Encodable
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TSAClientBouncyCastle.getTimeStampToken(TSAClientBouncyCastle.java:146)
... 3 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Encodable
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 4 more
```

But I see Class ASN1Encodable in the jar file bcprov-jdk15-1.43.jar. I dont understand what is the problem.

Comment: There's a serious problem with the version of iText you're using. I see my name in the package names, which makes me believe you are using iText, but you mention that you're using iText 4.2.0 and that is a version that doesn't exist. The official release jumped from 2.1.7 to 5.0.0. See http://itextpdf.com/changelog for more info. You have probably obtained a rogue version of iText. I would not use that version if I were you.

Comment: Please advice me what versions of itext and bouncy castle should I download for pdf signing with ltv enabled and timestamp. And also it must be free for commercial use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please also send me the link for ITextSharp changelog as we are using .net in another application. Please advice the free version of ITextSharp to use.

Comment: LTV has been added very recently and is only available in the AGPL version. Starting with iText 5, the iTextSharp changelog is identical to the iText changelog. You also need to understand the difference between free and gratis. AGPL software is free, but not gratis. Software that is available under the AGPL can be used without paying a fee as long as you make your software also completely free under the AGPL. If you want to use this functionality in a commercial context, you shouldn't ask for a gratis version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That exception means that the classloader cannot find that class at runtime.  We don't have enough information to determine why it is the case ... but it is definitely the cause of your problems.

Check that the offending JAR file is actually on your application's effective runtime classpath.

Comment: I checked the runtime classpath in eclipse by clicking run configurations and it is pointing to the right jar file.

Comment: When what the classpath is when you actually run the application; e.g. by running "ps -av" and looking at the command-line arguments.  You are missing something ...

Comment: I added the jars to the JRE libraries in addition to referenced libraries and it is executing fine. IT signed well but still I cannot see the timestamp on the signature it says 'Since the signature was applied' but not the time when it was applied.